# FlyoutPage on Xamarin formx 5.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Om Xamarin Forms we use this code to create Master Page:

```
 <MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Priority="0" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource MasterPageControls}" Command="{Binding ControlsCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="1" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource Refresh}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="2" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource About}" Command="{Binding AboutCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="4" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource Logout}" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <NavigationPage Title="Title" IconImageSource="hamburger.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu" 
                             BackgroundColor="White"
                             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
 ....
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Now i migrate my code to version 5.0 and i change it like this ([from this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/185872/changes-to-masterdetail-in-xamarin-forms-5)):

```
 <FlyoutPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Priority="0" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource MasterPageControls}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="1" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource Refresh}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="2" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource About}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="4" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource Logout}"/>
    </FlyoutPage.ToolbarItems>
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <NavigationPage Title="Title" IconImageSource="hamburger.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu" 
                             BackgroundColor="White"
                             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
               ...
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
```

Register:

```
           containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>("NavigationPage");
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PrismMasterDetailPage, PrismMasterDetailPageViewModel>("MasterPage");
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
```

And navigation:

```
 await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MasterPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

When i try run application i got this exception:
Flyout and Detail must be set before using a FlyoutPage

What should i change in my code to work it correctly (it should show on right side MasterPage and on center of the screen MainPage) ?

EDIT:
I change my code by adding a login page. It run on App.xaml.cs likt this:

```
 await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"/NavigationPage/{nameof(LoginPage)}");
```

On LoginPageViewModel i have binded command to button where i run a method to navigate to MainPage. In Xamarin.Forms 4.8 we use that command:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MasterPage/NavigationPage/MainPage",
                    new NavigationParameters {{nameof(LoginPageViewModel), string.Empty}});
```

But now when i use it Navigation didn't work (not have any exception or somethink like that):(

When i remove /MasterPage from name i'm navigate to MainPage but i not have my MasterPage

Edit 2:
I change code form use FlyoutPage to MasterDetailPage and it start work, but MasterDetailPage is obsolete in xamarin forms 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlyoutPage is not supported by Prism 8. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952867/xamarin-forms-flyoutpage-is-not-working-with-prism) and [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2239).

Comment: Yes, but MasterDetailPage is obsolete on XamarinForms 5:(

Comment: Ok i change my code to use obsolete MasterDetailPage and it start work

Comment: It's just a warning that it is obsolete, but you can still use it until Prism is updated to 8.1. Otherwise, you will not be able to navigate with FlyoutPage and Prism 8.0.

Comment: Yes i need to wait for 8.1

Answer (score 0):

AS the error shows `Flyout and Detail must be set before using a FlyoutPage` .

Try to set `FlyoutPage.Detail` as well in FlyoutPage xaml .

```
 <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <NavigationPage Title="Title" IconImageSource="hamburger.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu" 
                             BackgroundColor="White"
                             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
               ...
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>

<FlyoutPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <pages:FlyoutPage1Detail />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </FlyoutPage.Detail>
```

Refr to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage#create-a-flyoutpage.

Comment: I change somethink in code by using a LoginPage before FlyoutPage. Please see my edidet post

Comment: Ok , could you post your workaround  and mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Prism 8 didn't support FlyoutPage, so when i back to:

```
 <MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Priority="0" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource MasterPageControls}" Command="{Binding ControlsCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="1" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource Refresh}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="2" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource About}" Command="{Binding AboutCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Priority="4" Order="Secondary" Text="{x:DynamicResource Logout}" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <NavigationPage Title="Title" IconImageSource="hamburger.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu" 
                             BackgroundColor="White"
                             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
 ....
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

It start work, but i have warning becouse MasterDetailPage is obsolete but work :) I need to wait for Prism 8.1 and migrate MasterDetailPage to FlyoutPage